# Extracting indices of a data frame based on samples (with replacement) of a factor

Tags: r, dataframe, vectorization, sampling

I'm trying to figure out how to sample from the unique values of a factor (a unique identifier) in a data frame -- with replacement -- and then use those (repeated) sampled values to get the indexes of the values of the unique identifier to be sample.

More concretely, say I've got a dataset of (repeated) letters and numbers.  I want to sample unique values of the letters, and then return the indices of the data frame that correspond with the letters that I sampled.

```
set.seed(1)
df = data.frame(l = rep(letters,2), v = 1:52)
sampvec <- sample(letters, 10, replace = TRUE)
length(unique(sampvec))#Fewer than 10 unique values
idx <- which(df$l %in% sampvec)
length(idx) #there should be 20, but there are 18, because one of the letters is duplicated
```

This is trivial to do with a `for` loop, but would be too slow with real data:

```
idx <- c()
for (i in 1:length(sampvec)){
  idx <- append(idx, which(df$l %in% sampvec[i]))
}
```

Any vectorized way to do this?

Comment: @Jota If the letter "A" is sampled twice, I want the indices `[1,27]` to appear twice in `idx`

Comment: @Henrik very clever use of `merge`!  I think that works.  Make it an answer if you want some points

Comment: have you checked if the below works? can you also show what's in your sampvec?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `matchAll()` function from the `tuple` package. Unlike `match()`, it identifies all matching values instead of only the first one. The below assumes `l$v` is equal to index number like in your example.

```
library(tuple)
x[matchAll(sampvec, x$l),]$v
#[1]  7 10 15 24  6 24 25 18 17  2 33 36 41 50 32 50 51 44 43 28
```